# Yahoo YQL console not working for finanace table

Tags: console, yahoo, yql, stocks

I am just trying to do some test calls to the API via the yahoo YQL console : https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

But when I even try to do simple calls that should work, I am getting undefined table error

When I try:
    `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes`

It returns "No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes" in the xml.

What the hell?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's because `yahoo.finance.quotes` is a community data table. More details about community data tables here: http://www.datatables.org/ .In order to access this table you need to enable access to them in the console by clicking "Show Community Tables" checkbox on top-left part of the console.
[image]

Run your query after that.

**Note:** After you get the community tables working, if you run your YQL query, you will find you are missing a required parameter "symbol". If you want to get quote details for Facebook(FB) then you can do `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol='FB'`. Hope this helps